# When clicked on the show page json file

Tags: javascript, json

Help me please
Sorry for the mistakes I have low level of English

I have a json file

**JSON:**

```
var myArray = [
{
"display": "tiger",
"color": "yellow",
"url" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTC_tvQ-
   ZxUuaIvfEmBWy9JhHdABpy2C6yLGMkGZGQLJeANSE5o"
"about" : "The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest cat species, most 
recognisable for their pattern of dark vertical stripes on reddish-orange 
fur with a lighter underside. The species is classified in the genus 
Panthera with the lion, leopard, jaguar and snow leopard.",
},
{ "display": "krokodile",
 "color" : "green"
},
{ 
 "display": "chicken",
 "color": "yellow"
}
];
```

I create a page on which a button. I need to make when you press this button show up on the screen JSON file. With pictures and a brief description (color, some text)

Comment: This is not a question, this is a job. Do some research on reading file with js.

Comment: I  not asked to do the job. I'm only asked to help create a button that displays a file JSON. Maybe I do not understand something in this forum ...

Answer (score 0):

Example for the Same

```
var data = [
                    {
                     "name": "Rehan",
                     "location": "Pune",
                     "description": "hello hi",
                     "created_by": 13692,
                     "users_name": "xyz",
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Sameer",
                      "location": "Bangalore",
                      "description": "how are you",
                      "created_by": 13543,
                      "users_name": "abc",
                    },
                ]
        var htmlText = '';

        for ( var key in data ) {
            htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[key].name + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-loc"> Location: ' + data[key].location + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-desc"> Description: ' + data[key].description + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-created"> Created by: ' + data[key].created_by + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-uname"> Username: ' + data[key].users_name + '</p>';
            htmlText += '</div>';
        }

        $('body').append(htmlText);
```

Comment: It is inserted into the file index.html? I understand little, because only recently begun to study

Comment: just change it for ur file

Comment: this is html not java you need to first get the basics right

Comment: ohh okay it works right ? you choose the language as java in ideone

Comment: I work in the program WebMatrix. I dropped my code http://ideone.com/ the site just to show it to you. not to compile

Comment: This is the code in action https://jsbin.com/jinuguzano/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ooo! Thank you very much !! You can still help me in some ways, if you have the time?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using jQuery.
Check this fiddle : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owv3e2j9/)

```
var myArray = [{
"display": "tiger",
"color": "yellow",
"url" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTC_tvQ-ZxUuaIvfEmBWy9JhHdABpy2C6yLGMkGZGQLJeANSE5o",
"about" : "The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest cat species, most recognisable for their pattern of dark vertical stripes on reddish-orange fur with a lighter underside. The species is classified in the genus Panthera with the lion, leopard, jaguar and snow leopard."},{ 
"display": "krokodile",
"color" : "green",
"url" : "some url",
"about" : "some description"},{ 
"display": "chicken",
"color": "yellow",
"url" : "some url",
"about" : "some description"}];

element = 0;
$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
    $("#anName").text(myArray[element].display);
    $("#anColor").text(myArray[element].color);
    $("#anImg").attr('src',myArray[element].url);
    $("#anDescription").text(myArray[element].about);
    element++;
    if(element == myArray.length) element = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your JSON string, please have a look at below fiddle :

```
var myArray = [
{
"display": "tiger",
"color": "yellow",
"url" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTC_tvQ-ZxUuaIvfEmBWy9JhHdABpy2C6yLGMkGZGQLJeANSE5o",
"about" : "The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest cat species, most recognisable for their pattern of dark vertical stripes on reddish-orange fur with a lighter underside. The species is classified in the genus Panthera with the lion, leopard, jaguar and snow leopard."
},
{ "display": "krokodile",
"color" : "green"
},
{ 
"display": "chicken",
"color": "yellow"
}
];
var htmlContent = '';

for ( var obj in myArray ) {
htmlContent += '<div>';
htmlContent += '<p> Display: ' + myArray[obj].display + '</p>';            
            htmlContent += '<p> Color: ' + myArray[obj].color + '</p>';            
            htmlContent += '<img src="' + myArray[obj].url + '" height=200/>';         
            htmlContent += '<p> About : ' + myArray[obj].about + '</p>';            
htmlContent += '</div>';
}
$('body').append(htmlContent);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nisheshpratap/k5ok9rjf/

Comment: Maybe i'm so fool.. But this is my code. https://jsfiddle.net/mn3mjewx/

Comment: I am a student from Ukraine. I know very little programming, but I want to learn